# Infinispan deserialization white list : Class '[I'

Tags: java, infinispan

I am using Infinispan alongside hibernate on my project and I encountered a strange error log:

> ISPN000936: Class '[I' blocked by deserialization white list. Adjust the configuration serialization white list regular expression to include this class

I already have this issue but with normal class name so I could resolve the problem by adding the class to the serialization white-list like this:

```
globalConfigurationBuilder
        .serialization()
        .marshaller(new JavaSerializationMarshaller())
        .whiteList()
        .addClass(MyClass.class.getName());
```

but with this strange class name (`'[I'`)  I can't do this.
I can solve the problem by authorizing all the class in the serialization white-list like this :

```
globalConfigurationBuilder
        .serialization()
        .marshaller(new JavaSerializationMarshaller())
        .whiteList()
        .addRegexp(".*");
```

But I would like handle the problem in a more proper way.
Does someone have encountered the same issue and managed to solved it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[I` is the internal name for an `int[]`, so you can use any of the following:

```
.addClass​("[I")

.addClass​(int[].class.getName())

.addClasses(int[].class)
```

When you have more than one, I'd use the last one, which is a vararg method, e.g.

```
.addClasses(MyClass.class,
            FooClass.class,
            BarClass.class,
            int[].class)
```