# Infinispan 13.0.6 - Error putting custom java classes (POJO) in cache via WildFly 26.0.1.Final

Tags: java, wildfly, pojo, infinispan

I'm using WildFly26.0.1.Final to connect to Infinispan 13.0.6 and when I try to put an POJO object in a Infinispan cache I got this error:

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException:
Request for messageId=15 returned server error (status=0x85): org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: 
ISPN000936: Class 'pt.pe.sipe.storefrontmanager.api.artigo.SampleDTO' blocked by deserialization allow list. 
Adjust the configuration serialization allow list regular expression to include this class."}}
```

My configuration is:

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder =  new ConfigurationBuilder(); 
    builder.addServer().host("server")
            .port(11222)
            .security()
            .authentication()
            .username("admin")
            .password("password")
            .addJavaSerialWhiteList("pt.pe.sipe.*") //you can set the class name or use regex
            .marshaller(JavaSerializationMarshaller.class);
    
    RemoteCacheManager rim = new RemoteCacheManager(builder.build());
    
    cache = rim.getCache("teste15Fev22");
    
    SampleDTO fd = new SampleDTO();
    fd.setDescTipo("Franqueira");
    System.out.println("A adicionar à cache A");
    cache.put("A", fd);
    System.out.println("Em cache: "+cache.get("A").getClass());
```

**The full stack trace is:**

```
2022-02-16 17:41:51,825 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 215) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."emporium-ear.ear"."emporium-ejb.jar".component.CacheManager.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."emporium-ear.ear"."emporium-ejb.jar".component.CacheManager.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
at org.jboss.as.ee@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:57)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
at org.jboss.as.ee@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:170)
at org.jboss.as.ee@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:141)
at org.jboss.as.ee@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:127)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:141)
at org.jboss.as.ee@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54)
... 8 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException:Request for messageId=15 returned server error (status=0x85): org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: ISPN000936: Class 'pt.pe.sipe.storefrontmanager.api.artigo.SampleDTO' blocked by deserialization allow list. Adjust the configuration serialization allow list regular expression to include this class.
at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInNoTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.supports(CMTTxInterceptor.java:446)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:70)
at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.weld@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ee@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.StartupCountDownInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupCountDownInterceptor.java:25)
at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation@1.7.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:168)
... 13 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException:Request for messageId=15 returned server error (status=0x85): org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: ISPN000936: Class 'pt.pe.sipe.storefrontmanager.api.artigo.SampleDTO' blocked by deserialization allow list. Adjust the configuration serialization allow list regular expression to include this class.
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.org.infinispan-infinispan-client-hotrod-13.0.6.Final.jar//org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.protocol.Codec20.checkForErrorsInResponseStatus(Codec20.java:323)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.org.infinispan-infinispan-client-hotrod-13.0.6.Final.jar//org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.protocol.Codec20.readHeader(Codec20.java:168)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.org.infinispan-infinispan-client-hotrod-13.0.6.Final.jar//org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.transport.netty.HeaderDecoder.decode(HeaderDecoder.java:139)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.org.infinispan-infinispan-client-hotrod-13.0.6.Final.jar//org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.transport.netty.HintedReplayingDecoder.callDecode(HintedReplayingDecoder.java:94)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-codec-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-handler-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
at deployment.emporium-ear.ear.io.netty-netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

2022-02-16 17:41:51,826 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"emporium-ear.ear\".\"emporium-ejb.jar\".component.CacheManager.START" => "java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException:Request for messageId=15 returned server error (status=0x85): org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: ISPN000936: Class 'pt.pe.sipe.storefrontmanager.api.artigo.SampleDTO' blocked by deserialization allow list. Adjust the configuration serialization allow list regular expression to include this class.
Caused by: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException:Request for messageId=15 returned server error (status=0x85): org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: ISPN000936: Class 'pt.pe.sipe.storefrontmanager.api.artigo.SampleDTO' blocked by deserialization allow list. Adjust the configuration serialization allow list regular expression to include this class."}}
2022-02-16 17:41:51,826 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"emporium-ear.ear\".\"emporium-ejb.jar\".component.CacheManager.START" => "java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException:Request for messageId=15 returned server error (status=0x85): org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: ISPN000936: Class 'pt.pe.sipe.storefrontmanager.api.artigo.SampleDTO' blocked by deserialization allow list. Adjust the configuration serialization allow list regular expression to include this class.
Caused by: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException:Request for messageId=15 returned server error (status=0x85): org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: ISPN000936: Class 'pt.pe.sipe.storefrontmanager.api.artigo.SampleDTO' blocked by deserialization allow list. Adjust the configuration serialization allow list regular expression to include this class."}}
```

Thanks, Manuel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinispan deserialization white list : Class '\[I'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437650/infinispan-deserialization-white-list-class-i)

Comment: Does not work for me, but thanks anyway. ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
     builder.addServer()
              .host("server")
              .port(11222)
            .security().authentication()
              .username("admin")
              .password("password")
              .marshaller(new JavaSerializationMarshaller()).addJavaSerialAllowList(".*");
     remoteCacheManager = new RemoteCacheManager(builder.build());
        cache = remoteCacheManager.getCache("teste15Fev22");

Comment: can you share the exception full stack trace?

Comment: I share it above. Thanks!

Comment: I update my ticket to became more readable. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the cache configuration. In earlier versions of Infinispan we need to define/create a cache. In older versions I use default cache and have no problem.

My working cache configuration:

```
{
  "distributed-cache": {
    "mode": "SYNC",
    "statistics": true,
    "encoding": {
      "key": {
        "media-type": "application/x-java-serialized-object"
      },
      "value": {
        "media-type": "application/x-java-serialized-object"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Permissions problem I had in past (**blocked by deserialization allow list. Adjust the configuration serialization allow list regular expression to include this class.**) accessing classes manifested itself when I had the following configuration media-type "**application/x-java-object**". This configuration does not work!

Thanks for your help!